# Type Guards on property values not working when iterating through Object.keys()

Tags: typescript

I created a type guard to check if a value is an `Array`

```
const isArray = (value: unknown): value is [] => Array.isArray(value);
```

I am iterating over an object, check if the value of a property is an Array and print its length. The line inside of the condition raising a type error.

```
const obj: Record<string, unknown> = {};

Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    if (isArray(obj[key])) {
        console.log(obj[key].length);  // [typescript] Object is of type 'unknown'.
    }
});
```

If I use a temporary variable and apply type guard on the variable, everything works.

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    const value = obj[key];
    if (isArray(value)) {
        console.log(value.length);
    }
});
```

Is there a way to achieve this without a temporary variable? I am iterating through multiple arrays simultaneously and using several type guards. So, I have to use a lot of temporary variables.

Comment: If you use the `key` only for extracting the value - you can iterate over the values directly using `Object.values`. If you need both key and value - you can use `Object.entries`

Comment: By the way you can use `Array.isArray` directly (it is type guard itself), no need to wrap it with your own

Comment: **TYPO** alert - it's a **guard** - not a "gaurd" ....

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work because at the type-level the compiler doesn't have information about what record member the type guard was applied against.

The type of `key` is just `string`, and the compiler can't auto-cast `obj` to a `Record` where the value corresponding to all `string` keys is an array because that would be obviously wrong.

So, while the simplest solution is to use a temporary variable, as you have already found out, if you really need to skip temporary variables, you will have to:

1. Ditch the Record type and use a type for which the keys can be distinguished at the type level.
2. Adopt a type guard that can act on the type of the record itself and not a record member.

Example:

```
// const obj: Record<string, unknown> = {};
type Obj = { a: unknown, b: unknown, c: unknown};
const obj: Obj = {a: [], b: {}, c: {}};

// We need to cast Object.keys to a signature
// that preserves the information that returned value
// is list of keys of passed object's type
const keys = Object.keys as <T extends {}>(i: T) => Array<keyof T & string>;

const checkMemberArray = <K extends string & keyof Obj>(obj: Obj, key: K): obj is Obj & 
    {[k in K]: any[]} => isArray(obj[key]);

keys(obj).forEach(<K extends keyof Obj>(key: K) => {
    if (checkMemberArray(obj, key)) {
        // Type of obj within this block is
        // Obj & { [k in K]: any[]; }
        console.log(obj[key].length); // TS will not complain as long as you use key
    }
});
```

One may be inclined to skip the generic parameter of the function passed to forEach but that will be incorrect because that will cause typescript to infer the type for all values as arrays.

```
keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    if (checkMemberArray(obj, key)) {
        // Type of obj within this block is
        // {a: any[], b: any[], c: any[]}
        console.log(obj["b"].length); // TS fails to identify the error here
    }
});
```